# Help installing Wine 7 on 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, windows, wine, ubuntu-studio

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
```

*Ubuntu-Studio to be exact*

I am using  20.04 focal-fassa. I have follow the steps from the WineHQ and this video here "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dolxkfk-P-c" .

It says it depends on wine-impish but I already know that I cant use that version.

I tried [see below] to remove and start from scratch the redid the steps , but same results:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove wine
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

*Is there a way I can ignore this dependencies?*
*Is there another way to install?*
*Do I have to rebuild my entire distro?is my system ruined?*

*Is this a manufacturer issue?*

```
system         HP Pavilion Laptop
```

*Is this a cpu issue?*

```
processor      AMD Ryzen 5 5500U with Radeon Graphics
```

***should I rm -rf and install windows? (I don't want to vm) its native or bust***

**I have been at this for over a year now.**

(Here is what I always end with )

```
$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 7.0.0.0~impish-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages). This looks like a major [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) to me. You have this problem with your package manager you need to solve. It's also not clear why you need this particular version of Wine. Installing wine is not usually a goal, it is means to an end. Always ask about the actual problem you are trying to solve and describe your true end goal

Comment: Why do you think you need that specific version? Unless you actually need it then it's ALWAYS preferable to install from the official repositories, NOT from WineHQ's PPA.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: @Nmath My goal with Wine is to run some windows application that have not yet been ported to linux without VM. For me install Wine was the Goal when I switch to linux. I have succeed with every other program except Wine and omnisharp(separate issue).

Comment: In that case, this is definitely an XY problem. What you've asked about is many orders of operation away from what you're actually trying to do. You should be asking how to run that particular application. Not all Windows software can even be run with Wine. Have you looked to see if the application has any information on WineHQ?